# Find sum till $n$ terms:

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find sum till $n$ terms:
>
> > $$\cfrac{4}{1.2.3}+\cfrac{5}{2.3.4}+\cfrac{6}{3.4.5}+.....$$

I found the $n^{th}$ term as follows:

$$\cfrac{n+3}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$

So, we need to find:

$$\sum^n _{r=1}\cfrac{r+3}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$$
But I do not know how to solve further. I want to do it in a way such that I can form $V_n - V_{n-1}$ and all the other terms cancel out. But I am not getting how to split the numerator in the desired way. I'd be grateful if someone shared hints/solutions for this question. Thanks a lot.

---

We are doing loads of such questions in class, and my teacher always claims that intuition is really important for getting till the splitting. (After that, the rest is just cancellation, and it is pretty easy.)

But I don't get the hang of this intuition business, I always end up making mistakes and staying unsatisfied, because there isn't a "straight-forward" approach. Could someone please give advices on how to do such questions? I would be really glad if a full proof method is shared. Thanks :-)

Comment: Hint: split $r+3$ into $r$ and $3$. You now have two terms. Use partial fractions on each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that, the sequence simplifies to:
$$\left(\frac {1}{r(r+2)}+\frac {2}{r(r+1)(r+2)}\right)$$
Evaluate these sequences separately, both will telescope if you decompose to partial fractions.
The first one is very simple, for the second one consider that
$$\frac {2}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\left( \frac {(r+2)-r}{r(r+1)(r+2)}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood it, yes. But, could you tell how it clicked you to multiply and divide with $3$? It couldn't just have been out of the blue... I want to figure out how to approach these questions in general.

Comment: @Crease Google partial fraction decomposition. In general, when you have $\frac1{ab}$, if $b-a$ is simple, you can generally use some sort of partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Okay @DonThousand, I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: I noticed that in order to apply the telescope application, it would be useful if I could make the numerator constant. To do so, it could be a method to somehow take out the $n$ term, which can be done by seeing that $n+3=\frac 13 ((3n+3)+6)$.

Comment: @DonThousand, I checked it, but it isn't quite clear on how to separate the factors of the denominator into $2$ parts ($V_n - V_{n-1}$) if the factors are more than $2$. What do we do in that case?

Comment: without multiplying by 3 you can split sequences by writing numerator as $(r+1)+2$

Comment: @LalitTolani I tried that... I don't think that works.

Comment: @Crease I know you got the solution now, but in case you didn't want to multiply by $3$, check out the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I just now got an answer to my own question !!

$$\cfrac{n+3}{n(n+1)(n+2)}= \cfrac{n}{n(n+1)(n+2)} + \cfrac{3}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$

$$\implies \cfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+ 3\big[\cfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}\big]$$

$$\implies \cfrac{1}{n+1}-\cfrac{1}{n+2} + 3\cdot\cfrac{1}{2}\big[\cfrac{n+2-n}{n(n+1)(n+2)}\big] $$

$$\implies \cfrac{1}{n+1}-\cfrac{1}{n+2} + 3\cdot \cfrac{1}{2}\big[\cfrac{1}{n(n+1)} - \cfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\big] $$

The sigma's of this expression is known and is easy :-)

It maybe a bit lengthy but it is more relatable. Thanks to all the people who helped!

Answer (score 0):

@Crease , this answer is as an reply to your comment-

$$\cfrac{n+3}{n(n+1)(n+2)}= \cfrac{n+1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} + \cfrac{2}{n(n+1)(n+2)}= \cfrac{1}{n(n+2)} + \cfrac{2}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$
Now the term on left  can be split as $\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+4}$

Now the term on left  can be split as $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

Therefore you are left with following summations at last

$\sum^n _{r=1}(\frac{1}{2r}-\frac{1}{2r+4})$+$\sum^n _{r=1}(\frac{1}{r(r+1)}-\frac{1}{(r+1)(r+2)})$ which can be written as

$\frac{1}{2}\sum^n _{r=1}(V_x-V_{x+2})$+$\frac{1}{2}\sum^n _{r=1}(V_y-V_{y+1})$

$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2})$+$(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)})$ which you can further simplify

Comment: thanks for your answer!

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

As this is a Telescopic series , we can use . $$\frac{1}{a.b.c}=\frac{1}{c-a}\left(\frac{1}{a.b}-\frac{1}{b.c}\right)$$ And , $$\frac{1}{a.b}=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)$$

So , here : $$\frac{4}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1.2}-\frac{1}{2.3}\right)+\frac{5}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2.3}-\frac{1}{3.4}\right)+........+\frac{(n+3)}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{4}{1.2}+\frac{1}{2.3}+\frac{1}{3.2}+.......+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{(n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right]$$ $$\frac{1}{2}\left[2+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)}-\frac{(n+3)}{(n+2)(n+2)}\right]$$ So , $$T_n=\frac{5}{4}-\frac{2n+5}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$

Comment: There might be some Calculation mistakes , but still you can use above two formulas to froceed to solution .

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Nice method, it would help me generalize more such problems.

Comment: Better answer than mine

Comment: No problem ......Remember these formulas , they'll be helpful !

Comment: You guys can UpVote if you like , the solution ! Its totally FREE